# Angular2: Type NgModel is part of the declarations of 2 modules: FormsModule and SharedModule

Tags: angular

I get

> Uncaught Type NgModel is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
>   FormsModule and SharedModule!

while I'm upgrade Angular2 from rc.4 to rc.5.

My `SharedModule` is like (I remove similar components and services, just leave one of them below)

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AlertComponent } from './sharedcomponents/apcomponents/alert/alert.component';

import { MonitorService } from './sharedservices/restapi/monitor.service';


@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule ],
    declarations: [
                    AlertComponent,
                ],
    exports:    [
                    CommonModule,
                    FormsModule,
                    HttpModule,
                    AlertComponent,
                ]
})
export class SharedModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
                    MonitorService
                ]
    };
  }
}
```

I check all my componets and there is no NgModel imported at all.

EDIT: add `app.module`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        routing,
        SharedModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],

    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: How does your `AppModule` looks like?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan edited question and added `app.module`

Comment: Is Alert component using any Directive? can you add @Component Metadata for AlertComponent?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan After add `FormsModule` to `@NgModule` imports as described in the comment of below answer, this issue has been resolved. It turns out that I have components rely on directives inside `FormsModule` but I didn't import in the `SharedModule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import FormsModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule]
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Thanks

Comment: You just import the commonModule, you should import the formsModule as well before exporting it: @NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule, FormsModule ].

Comment: After add `FormsModule` to imports, I get `Uncaught Type FormControlDirective is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ReactiveFormsModule and SharedModule!`. And, I don't have `FormControlDirective` either.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I should have imported `ReactiveFormsModule` as well.

Comment: Could you edit your answer so that I can accept it? "FormModel" is a typo.

Comment: I did, thanks! I still do get why in the Angular example http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview it does work without importing FormsModule anywhere. I will search for the answer :)

Comment: They said "the SharedModule didn't import FormsModule because its components don't need it. Angular lets us re-export a module even if we don't import it." I think in their case, the actual "shared" component doesn't use anything from FormsModule and other modules/components who import the SharedModule use the SharedModule to help them import the FormsModule.

Comment: That will be the case. But the term: re-export  is a bit strange for me. If you import something that imports another module I understand you can re-export it. But without importing it anywhere..  Anyway I guess an import of a module means importing all exports of the module you import. That makes sense. I'm going to check my code on unnecessary imports ;-)